# Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'These are comments for errors' to data type int

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have been struggling to get this corrected for a while now. Below is the part of a query where I am getting the error in the `MAX` function and I am not able to understand why its trying to convert to data type `INT`. I would like to keep it as string as this particular column is for comments

```
 MAX(CASE  
        WHEN ID = -416 AND Value IS NOT NULL 
          THEN Value 
          ELSE 'No Error' 
     END) AS Error_Comments
```

This particular table is still in test and hence for test purposes there is only one comment added for now which is

> These are comments for errors

I also tried converting the case statement but it still gives the same error:

```
MAX(CONVERT(VARCHAR, CASE 
                        WHEN ID = -416 AND Value IS NOT NULL 
                           THEN Value 
                           ELSE 'No Error' 
                     END)) AS Error_Comments
```

I also tried this but didn't work:  `Value <> ''`

I couldn't find the answer in any of the stackoverflow questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
declare @t table(ID int, value nvarchar(1000))
insert @t values(-416, 'These are comments for errors'),
(-416, null)

SELECT 
COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN ID = -416 THEN value END), 'No Error') AS Error_Comments
FROM @t
```

Result:

```
These are comments for errors
```

Comment: ID is `INT` and Value is `NVARCHAR(1000)`

Comment: of course not, but how do you intend to take the max value of a varchar ?

Comment: I am sorry, I am not able to understand the question. Do I need to give you more information about the query. There are four other `MIN` functions used in this query. But those work fine. Shall I edit my question?

Comment: @Excited_to_learn solved the answer with an example, I bet your issue is elsewhere in your query, try to omit those other aggregate functions when testing

Comment: I am a reports developer and I have access to only SSRS tool. But will try look into the query for errors. thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2):

It would seem that `value` is an integer.  So, your `case` statement is returning different types, and SQL Server has decided that the type should be an integer.  Your string doesn't convert.

So, do an explicit conversion:

```
MAX(CASE WHEN ID = -416 AND Value IS NOT NULL THEN cast(Value as varchar(255))
         ELSE 'No Error'
    END) AS Error_Comments
```

EDIT:

The comment makes a lot of sense.  I suppose this should be:

```
COALESCE(CAST(CASE WHEN ID = -416 AND Value IS NOT NULL THEN VALUE END) as varchar(255)),
         'No Error'
        )
```

Comment: I tried your solution but its giving th same error.

Comment: this will give a funky result, taking the max value and maybe get a 'No error' if the rest of the varchars has a lower value. Example with 3 errors: select max(error) from (values('a'),('b'),('no error')) x(error)